# Jackson is ignoring XmlAccessorType.NONE

Tags: java, json, jackson

My pojo class is annotated with XmlAccessorType.NONE.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Human {

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    private String name;

    private int age

}
```

JSON which im trying to read contains both properties name and age. If i annotate the class with JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) everything works However if i try to use annotation XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) intead, jackson throws unknown property exception.

I tried to add JaxbAnnotationIntrospector into objectmapper but it did not help    `mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why `XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` would be relevant here,
It would affect discovery of properties available (no auto-discovery), but NOT what to do with JSON/XML properties for which there is no Bean property.

The difference here is probably more due to difference between defaults for JAXB and Jackson: by default, JAXB silently ignores anything it does not recognize. By default Jackson throws an exception when it does not recognize something.

If you want, you can configure `ObjectMapper` to ignore these problems by default:

napper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

so that behavior is similar to that of JAXB.

Comment: setting config value FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false fixed my issue